# Как узнать дистанцию до ближайшего объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как определить расстояние до, скажем, ближайшего врага. Допустим, все враги под одним тегом. Я умею определять расстояние между только двумя конкретными объектами. А между одним и несколькими не умею.

Comment: очевидно придется пропахать объекты в цикле и выбрать наименьшую дистанцию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю надо не только дистанцию найти но и сам объект. Собственно это обычная задача на поиск минимума/максимума в коллекции.

- Находишь объекты с тегом через **[FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html)** и складываешь в переменную, допустим `targets`
- Также есть две изначальные переменные `GameObject closest = null;` — ближайший объект и `float distance = Mathf.Infinity;` — инициализация расстояния.
- Делаешь цикл `foreach (GameObject go in targets)` и сравниваешь их дистанцию с `distance`
- Если дистанция меньше, чем `distance`, то в `distance` записываешь дистанцию, получившуюся на данной итерации, а в `closest` записываешь объект `go`
- После окончания цикла в `closest` будет лежать как раз объект, который ближе к сравниваемому

Answer (score 0):

Определить расстояние до каждого из элементов, а затем отсортировать и взять элемент с наименьшим расстоянием.

Comment: Сортировать точно не надо, минимальное значение в массиве ищется быстрее чем сортировка этого массива

Comment: Получается, создать массив дистанций, а после найти наименьшую?

Comment: да, просто найти наименьшую

Comment: Андрей, смотря сколько элементов и смотря какая сортировка